# SecurityException: Media projections require a foreground service of type ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PROJECTION

Tags: java, android, windows, mobile, media

I'm facing a "SecurityException" with the message "Media projections require a foreground service of type ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PROJECTION" while trying to capture the screen on an Android device using the MediaProjection API.

I have followed the suggested solutions found in various online resources, including:

Ensuring the necessary permissions are declared in the AndroidManifest.xml file.
Requesting runtime permissions for recording audio and writing to external storage.
Registering a foreground service with the appropriate "foregroundServiceType" attribute set to "mediaProjection" in the manifest.
Despite implementing these steps, the security exception persists. Below is the relevant code:

```
// MainActivity.java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    // Variables and constants...

    public class MediaProjectionCallback extends MediaProjection.Callback {
        @Override
        public void onStop() {
            stopScreenSharing();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mProjectionManager = (MediaProjectionManager) getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);
        mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

        mToggleButton = findViewById(R.id.toggle);
        mToggleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mToggleButton.isChecked()) {
                    requestPermissions();
                } else {
                    stopScreenSharing();
                }
            }
        });

        startForegroundService(mProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent());
    }

    // Other methods...

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_SCREEN_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            mMediaProjectionCallback = new MediaProjectionCallback();
            mMediaProjection = mProjectionManager.getMediaProjection(resultCode, data);
            mMediaProjection.registerCallback(mMediaProjectionCallback, null);
            mVirtualDisplay = createVirtualDisplay();
            mMediaRecorder.start();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Screen Capture Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mToggleButton.setChecked(false);
        }
    }

    // Other code...
}
```

I'm using a Samsung Tab A8 running Android 13, and I've observed that this issue occurs specifically on this device and Android version. I have tested the code on other devices and Android versions, and it works correctly.

I'm looking for any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.